# R: How do I replace strings in a column with condition to a second column?

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements, subset, gsub

I have a small data frame like this:

```
a<-c("green","green","green","green","green","green","green","green","green","green")
b<-c("blue","red","blue","red","blue","red","blue","red","blue","red")
df<-data.frame(a,b)
df
       a    b
1  green blue
2  green  red
3  green blue
4  green  red
5  green blue
6  green  red
7  green blue
8  green  red
9  green blue
10 green  red
```

and I would like to replace the "green" by "yellow" where b=="red"

I can select these rows by `df[b=="red",]` but the replacement doesn't work. I tried:

```
> df[b=="red",]$a<-gsub("green","yellow",df[b=="red",])
Fehler in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "a", value = c("c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)",  : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 5
```

or

```
> df$a[subset(df$a,df$b=="red")]<-"yellow"
Warnmeldung:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, subset(df$a, df$b == "red"), value = c(NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> df
       a    b
1   <NA> blue
2  green  red
3  green blue
4  green  red
5  green blue
6  green  red
7  green blue
8  green  red
9  green blue
10 green  red
```

and

```
> df[b=="red",]$a<-"yellow"
Warnmeldung:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c("yellow", "yellow", "yellow",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> df
       a    b
1  green blue
2   <NA>  red
3  green blue
4   <NA>  red
5  green blue
6   <NA>  red
7  green blue
8   <NA>  red
9  green blue
10  <NA>  red
```

None of this works properly for my issue. What would be the simplest solution? Many thanks, Treppenlift.

Comment: Try `df <- data.frame(a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE); df[df$b == 'red', 1] <- 'yellow'`. The problem is that `R` sets `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` by default in a call to `data.frame`.

Comment: you need to have also 2 conditions : `df$b=="red"` and `df$a=="green"` incase of such cases in data

Comment: @bouncyball This solution works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the which functionality. For some examples see http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/which.php.

```
df[which(df[,2]=="red"),1] <- "yellow"
```

Comment: `which` is actually not necessary here. Removing the function will work just fine: `df[df[,2] == 'red', ]`